# AppCenter build crashes when building Flutter Android app

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, continuous-integration, visual-studio-app-center

I'm buiding a Flutter Android app with AppCenter build.

I have the following build script taken from [here](https://www.rocksolidknowledge.com/articles/using-appcenter-for-flutter-projects)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Place this script in project/android/app/
cd ..
# fail if any command fails
set -e
# debug log
set -x
cd ..
git clone -b dev https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH
flutter doctor
echo "Installed flutter to `pwd`/flutter"
flutter build apk --release
#copy the APK where AppCenter will find it
mkdir -p android/app/build/outputs/apk/; mv build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk $_
```

Here is an excerpt of the build log:

```
...    
Downloading ios-deploy...                                           0.4s
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.9.7, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G87, locale en)
    [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
        ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
    [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
    [!] Android Studio (not installed)
    [!] Connected device
        ! No devices available

    ! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
    ++ pwd
    + echo 'Installed flutter to /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/flutter'
    + flutter build apk --release
    Installed flutter to /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/flutter
    Running "flutter pub get" in s...                                   4.1s
    You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64.
    If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
        To generate an app bundle, run:
            flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
            Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
        To split the APKs per ABI, run:
            flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi
            Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
    Initializing gradle...                                          

    Sending crash report to Google.

...
```

Looks like AppCenter cannot initialize Gradle.
Any suggestions? 
.gitignore file:

```
# Android related
#**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
#**/android/gradlew
#**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
```

Comment: (I know its too late, but it may be helpful for others)  May be you can find something helpful here: https://medium.com/@rakhimov.sardorbek/flutter-apps-ci-cd-using-appcenter-ab68b4aee30f

Answer (score 1):

Is `flutter build apk --release` working locally?
Which build settings you are using in appcenter? Did you updated your .gitignore, like in the tutorial?

Please try to provide some more information. Had a similar problem and solved it by adding the `pre-post.sh` but it seems
you are having a different problem.

Try `flutter clean` and `flutter build`. Then try to push and build again.

Comment: Yes. I did update the .gignore. 
Flutter build apk --release is working locally.
flutter clean and flutter build apk run locally and pushed. 
AppCenter build fails...

Comment: Did you find the solution? I need help? Same issue

Comment: @AbdullahKhan check if your gradle files are pushed properly after editing the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing similar issue. An alternative way is just to release an apk to the release section of the appcenter.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I need help? Same issue

Comment: This is indeed a workaround, but for those of us trying to setup a release pipeline not a solution. It would be good to know the eventual resolution from those who have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the non-accepted android licenses are slowing down things.. since you're using some android packages..

try

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and accept all licenses, then give another try